# How to fix build gradle

Tags: android, build

I restarted the Android Studio and an error occurred during the build

Build failed show:

```
C:\Users\aws hakam\Desktop\freeLance\BottleOfWater\app\build\intermediates\external_file_lib_dex_archives\debug\out
```

The extension it points to does not exist

The details error

```
    Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\aws hakam\Desktop\freeLance\BottleOfWater\app\build\intermediates\external_file_lib_dex_archives\debug\out
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsDirectoryStream.<init>(WindowsDirectoryStream.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:518)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:457)
    at java.nio.file.Files.list(Files.java:3451)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingParams.getAllDexFiles(DexMergingTask.kt:502)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskRunnable.run(DexMergingTask.kt:423)
    ... 28 more
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I encountered this same error in a React Native project I am working on. I was able to resolve the issue through the following. Be sure to replace `<PROJECT_NAME>` below with your actual project name.

1. Within Android Studio, select File > Invalid Cache and Restart.
2. Open your project directory in your terminal.
3. `rm -rf .gradle`
4. `rm -rf android/.gradle android/.idea`
5. `rm android/app/app.iml android/<PROJECT_NAME>.iml`

After doing this, I was able to open my project in Android Studio and successfully build. I had tried all but step 3 a few times without success, so my belief is that step 3 and the top-level `.gradle` directory in my project was the primary issue. I'm not sure how it got there.

One additional note, React Native projects place all of the Android-specific code inside an `android` directory. So, if your project is not a React Native project, and instead a traditional Android project, the paths I outlined for removal may be different (i.e. they wouldn't be underneath `android/`).

Comment: Life saver, thanks! How did you come up with those steps?

Comment: It’s been quite awhile since I posted. I’m not sure, but I would imagine largely trial and error. :)

Answer (score 24):

It helps me with Android Studio.

Delete .gradle dir in your project: rm -rf .gradle

Comment: This helped me on windows too. I had actually copied my project and opened it in another PC and that's why I was getting the same error. But deleting the .gradle folder from my project directory, worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

It took me 3 days, I finally found a simple solution:

In the android/app/build.gradle file.
Add line multiDexEnabled true

```
android {
defaultConfig {
    ...
    targetSdkVersion 28
    multiDexEnabled true // here
}
...
```

}

Answer (score 7):

For me just doing

```
rm -rf .gradle
```

and Restart and invalid worked in Android Studio

Comment: It's in your home folder, so better to run `rm -rf ~/.gradle`

Answer (score 1):

This error is usually related to xml files which could be in `drawable` or `layout` folder.

In my case there was a drawable I added and it was referring to a color "lightGray" `android:drawable="@color/lightGray"` which did not exist.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/lightGray" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/black_transparent"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Android Studio and Mac

- open terminal, move to the project folder

  `cd <path to the android project>`
- then remove the .gradle

  `rm -rf .gradle`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and actually created the folder `<project-root>/android/app/build/intermediates/external_file_lib_dex_archives/debug/out`

After that the build was successful.