# Can't install React Native app in debug mode after installing production build

Tags: android, react-native

I installed in my phone (not using an emulator) the release version of an app I'm building with React Native. After that, I can't install a debug version using `yarn android`.

This is the error I get:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Unknown failure: Exception occurred while executing 'install':
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error: Failed to parse APK file: /data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk: Failed to parse /data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk
```

I've tried deleting the release apk file from the build output. I've also deleted cleared the app's data and cache, and then deleted it from my phone. Still getting the same issue.

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65683714/react-native-android-debug-apk-is-not-installing-in-one-plus-nord) also didn't make it work.

Any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried running the project on Android Studio? How did you installed the release version of the app?

Comment: @Daniel Reina - how did you install the release version ? Have you created a signed apk or are you trying to install the debug apk? plz explain how did you install the apk in to phone

Comment: Did you do a gradle clean (`./gradlew clean`) and tried installing the app again ?

Comment: What helps me in this situation is using package manager to remove your app
adb shell pm  -k --user 0  uninstall com.example.MyApp

Comment: sometime android device(onePlus 7T) keeps the app installed in the other user also. So, deleting from the admin user only does not work. I had to switch to guest user and uninstall from there also.

Comment: @KarloA.López No, I didn't run it in Android Studio. I installed the release version by creating the release apk, then transferring it to the phone with Android File Transfer, and then opening the apk on the phone.

Comment: @PasinduDilshan Doing `./gradlew clean` didn't fix it right away, but it changed the error I was getting. I had faced the new error before, so I followed the same steps I took to fix it, and it's working again. Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

Following [Pasindu Dilshan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6514144/pasindu-dilshan)'s comment and with further debugging I ended up getting to a working state. Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction .

The steps I followed were:

1. Run `./gradlew clean` inside the "{project_path}/android". This gave me a new error in the task `:app:mergeExtDexDebug`, solvable with the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61219982/5452969), which I'll reproduce below for completion.
2. Within Android Studio, select File > Invalid Cache and Restart.
3. Open your project directory in your terminal.
4. `rm -rf .gradle`
5. `rm -rf android/.gradle android/.idea`
6. `rm android/app/app.iml android/<PROJECT_NAME>.iml`

For reference, I'll note that steps 3. and 6. were not necessary in my particular case because those folders and files didn't exist in my project. However, they should be removed if they exist in yours.

Shout out to [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/378228/david) for steps 2-6.